# How to center absolute position element in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an element in the center of the parent element
My question is how to make it always center responsively.

I have something like

html

```
<div class="test">
    <span class="d1">Test 1</span>
    <span class="d2">Test 2</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.test {
    position:relative;
}

.d1 {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #789845;
}

.d2 {
    position: absolute;
    top:40%;
    left: ( not sure what to put here), I want this element always in the center no matter the width of browser is.
    width: 100px;
    background-color:#EEEE78;
}
```

I am not sure how to set the `left` value because if I set a static value, it will always be a bit off on varies browser width. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any `absoulte` position element - exists just one overall rule `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0; right: 0;`.

Also, you should add width to your parent element, then children will know where is center. In your case it's `.test` class with `width: 100%;` (you can change it, as you want).

```css
.test {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.d1 {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #789845;
}

.d2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:#EEEE78;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <span class="d1">Test 1</span>
    <span class="d2">Test 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1- You can use `left: 50%` and `transform` (for unknown width) to achieve what you want like this:

```css
.test {
    position:relative;
}

.d1 {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #789845;
}

.d2 {
    position: absolute;
    top:40%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:#EEEE78;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <span class="d1">Test 1</span>
    <span class="d2">Test 2</span>
</div>
```

2- or you can use `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -(half width)` (for known width)

```css
.test {
    position:relative;
}

.d1 {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #789845;
}

.d2 {
    position: absolute;
    top:40%;
    background-color:#EEEE78;  
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* - the half of width (100 / 2) */
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <span class="d1">Test 1</span>
    <span class="d2">Test 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `left` `0` and `right` `0` as well as `margin-left` `auto` and `margin-right` `auto`. To avoid guessing always provide your fiddle.